# Python concurrent futures large number of inputs sit idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am processing large number of files (tens of millions) using Python's concurrent.futures.
Issuing a small number of inputs work fine, however when the input size increases, the processes just don't start.
Below code executes only when input size is small, e.g. 20_000.

```
import concurrent
import math

def some_math(x):
    y = 3*x**2 + 5*x + 7
    return math.log(y)

inputs = range(1_000_000)
results = []

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for result in executor.map(some_math, inputs):
        results.append(result)
```

I have tried to overcome this by submitting jobs in smaller batches as below:

```
import concurrent
import math
    
def some_math(x):
    y = 3*x**2 + 5*x + 7
    return math.log(y)

up_to = 220_000
batch_size = 20_000
results = []
for idx in range(0, up_to, batch_size):
    low = idx
    high = min(low + batch_size, up_to)
    
    inputs = range(low, high)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for result in executor.map(some_math, inputs):
            results.append(result)
```

But again, it either does not start at all, or gets stuck after a few iterations of the outer for loop.

My Python version is 3.10.7.
What is the issue here?

Comment: Use numpy or numba.

Comment: The function in the question is just an example, the real function is different and has nothing to do with vector math libraries.

Comment: When constructing the ProcessPoolExecutor, use a low value for max_workers e.g., 4. On my system (10 dual-core CPUs) if I allow the default, it gets stuck. All the created processes just sit idle. This is clearly a bug. ProcessPoolExecutor and ThreadPoolExecutor should be interchangeable. For this particular case (on my system) they clearly are not. Multithreading (<15s) runs 10 times faster than Multiprocessing (~150s) on my system. Given that the sub-process is CPU-bound, this should not be the case

Comment: @Pingu I tried setting max_workers to the cpu_count, that is provided by the multiprocessing library, and the result was the same: processors sitting idle.
However, using ThreadPoolExecutor allowed me to execute the code. I will look into whether using ThreadPoolExecutor causes an issue/delay with the function accessing a shared object due to GIL. Thanks.

Comment: @meliksahturker As a general rule, multiprocessing is better suited to CPU intensive work. I think the problem here is that your test code spends very little time in the sub-process or thread so it's not realistic. If your sub-process was doing a lot more work, you'd probably see very different results

Comment: @Pingu, I confirm your statement. Running my CPU intensive function for 10_000 inputs with ThreadPoolExecutor took 190s, whereas running it with ProcessPoolExecutor took only 3s. This is odd to me though, as I thought creating threads should be cheaper and hence, faster. I am open to any reading recommendation you can give about Python's concurrency. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take advantage of the `chunksize` parameter of the `map` function, the pool is simply a pipe with a shared lock, and having 10 or more processes contending over that lock is going to be very slow.

using a large chunksize reduces this contention, as each process is going to grab a larger chunk off the queue each time it takes the lock.

```py
import concurrent.futures
import math

def some_math(x):
    y = 3*x**2 + 5*x + 7
    return math.log(y)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputs = range(1_000_000)
    results = []

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for result in executor.map(some_math, inputs, chunksize=10_000):
            results.append(result)
```

in the above code the lock will only be locked 100 times instead of 1_000_000 times, and you get much less context switching.

Comment: This indeed works in terms of both preventing idle processors and faster execution. Thanks!